# enable ftp access, disable telnet and ssh for only some users

Tags: ftp, solaris

How can I enable only FTP access to the Solaris box, but not SSH and Telnet for only selected account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make "only ftp" users, meaning they can only use ftp, no telnet or ssh, do this:

1. add /bin/false to the list of shells in /etc/shells
2. change your user's shell to /bin/false

Comment: Some ftpds (vsftpd for example) will check the validity of the account this way. 
See option 'check_shell' in vsftpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Two things you might try:

1. You could use the virtual users feature of [vsftpd](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html). This would let you set up users entirely independent of the OS users. There is a [vsftpd](http://www.blastwave.org/jir/pkgcontents.ftd?software=vsftpd&style=brief&state=5&arch=sparc) package on blastwave.  This involves adding new piece of software, you might not want or be able to do that.
2. For ssh the `DenyUsers/DenyGroups` will stop ftpuser from loggin in. Something like this in ''sshd_config'':

DenyUsers ftpuser1 ftpuser2
DenyGroups ftpgroup

For telnet you could try to make the `ftpuser` shell = /usr/bin/false (put /usr/bin/false) in /etc/shells), that should stop him from logging in over telnet but I think allow ftp (I don't have a Solaris VM to test unfortunately).